# RewriteRule RewriteCond

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

These codes dont work together... How can I integrate both codes?

```
# Block#1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^search/(.+?)/(\d+)/?$ /search.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?q=([^\s]+)&p=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

# Block#2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^search/(.+?)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ /search.php?q=$1&p=$2&ty=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?q=([^\s]+)&p=(\d+)&ty=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain what you are trying to do and include exactly what is not working, what output you are getting and what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite directives execute top-down, so the most specific rules should come before the more general rules.

In your code above you need to reverse code *Block#1* and *Block#2*. ie. check for 3 URL params *before* checking for 2 URL params.

Alternatively, match the exact URL (rather than just a prefix) in the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive). Perhaps by matching a trailing *space* in the `THE_REQUEST` variable. eg `...&p=(\d+)\s [NC]`